# Delphi, Indy, how to send records efficiently

Tags: delphi, indy

When transferring records data via `IndyTCPClient` and `IndyTCPServer` I always use a simple approach - all records have a fixed size and are placed to the stream:
On the client side:

```
  type
    TUser = record
      i:integer;
      s:string[100];
      i64:Int64;
      s2:string[200];
    end;

  with idClient.Socket do
    begin
      MStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        MStream.Write(User, sizeOf(TUser));
        MStream.Seek(0, soBeginning);
        write(MStream, MStream.Size);
      finally
        MStream.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

On the server side:

```
  with AIdCondext.Connection.Socket do
  begin
    MStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ReadStream(MStream, sizeOf(TUser), False);
      MStream.Seek(0, soBeginning);
      MStream.read(User, MStream.Size);
    finally
      MStream.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

It works fine but it seems not very efficient cause I need to use fixed length strings which are almost always empty and also records often come as part of large arrays that need to be sent. Is there way to do it more efficiently without sending record members separately?

Comment: Do you want to be more efficient, or do you want to consider sending an entire record in one go? Seems like the latter constraint is going to hinder you.

Comment: Usually I have a lot of records with a lot of members and a lot of transfers, splitting them will cause the code look ugly

Comment: How many record-sends do you have to do, and how long does it take? Is that time too long for you?

Comment: I guess you have make your mind up then. Sounds like you have to choose between sending less data, or writing some code. It sounds like you want something for nothing. No need for it to be ugly if you do it well. And there can be other benefits, like not being tied to ANSI text!

Comment: I would like to know if it's possible that the code would be more effective than more uglier.

Comment: @nolaspeaker it's very situational, usually transfers are rare: once after program is loaded, TUser is around 3 kb, 100 users in array, TContact is around 4 kb and arrays could be of 100000 (very rare), mostly 1000-5000 length.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trade-off to what you are asking for. If you want the transmission on the wire to be more efficient (less bandwidth, etc), then you need to write more code to *serialize* each record into a more efficient format on the wire. Otherwise, you can write simpler code (for instance, using `TIdMemoryBufferStream` instead of `TMemoryStream`), which will allow you to transfer larger amounts of data using less code, but at the cost of using a less efficient transmission format. So you need to decide what will better suit your needs.

Comment: I see, so TIdMemoryBufferStream compresses records and then sends/receives them transparently. That's a good optimization though looks to me that to be effective all the fixed length strings should be filled with zeros like 'abcdef #0#0#0#0#...', right?

Comment: @Molochnik no, it does not compress anything, it simply allows you to send/receive data directly in memory (ie, from/to your records directly) without having to make a separate copy of the data, which your example does

Comment: Oh I see, I thought there is some function which allows you to send zipped records automatically

Comment: You can assign a `Compressor` component to the connection, such as `TIdCompressorZLib`, and that will (de)compress data back and forth.